# Thunderbolt dock screens not working after waking from sleep

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, suspend

I have a HP ZBook 15 G4 with both Intel 630 and Nvidia Quadro M1200 Mobile GPU with Nvidida driver 430 running 18.04.3. At work I have a Thunderbolt dock (https://store.hp.com/in-en/default/hp-zbook-200w-thunderbolt-3-dock-p5q61aa.html) that I connect to access my two external displays and mouse & keyboard. This works fine if I do a cold boot of the machine but if I would put Ubuntu to sleep, disconnect the thunderbolt cable and wake the machine the next day and connect, only the keyboard and mouse works, not the screens. The get them back working, I have to reboot my machine and thus closing all my open programs and files.

I have tried various graphics drivers but not been able to get this working. My dock is running the latest firmware as well as the bios of my machine.

How can I solve this issue? Could I somehow do a "soft" reboot of the driver or something else when waking it up?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My screens do not boot when I attach my laptop (in sleep mode) to the Thunderbolt system. The power button does not react to bring my laptop awake.

I have a workaround:

I open my screen of the laptop (so I wake it), then dock it to the Thunderbolt docking station until one of my other two external monitors reacts (always the wrong one). Then I close the lid again, so the laptop goes to sleep while plugged into the Thunderbolt docking station. And then I press the start-up button on the Thunderbolt docking station to re-wake my laptop. Now it shows all the information on the correct monitors, while the laptop lid is still closed.

I expect the Thunderbolt to recognize my laptop being asleep, and allow me to wake it by just pressing the power button on the Thunderbolt station (like any docking station). It does not react when the laptop is asleep. The Thunderbolt manuals say only to connect a laptop that has been completely shut down (which is a stupid limitation).